# Is it possible to use methods defined in refinements in Sinatra views?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, refinements

I have a class defined in a gem to which I am adding some methods via refinements (in Ruby 2.3.0).  This class turns up in some Sinatra views (haml).

When I refer to these extra methods in a helper, there is not a problem.  But in the view, I get an Undefined Method error.

Am I missing a trick, or is it that the `using ...` statement would need to go somewhere I just can't get to?

(Workaround: I can define helper methods to return the method on the object.  But if I wanted to do that then I wouldn't have used refinements...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of refinement is determined lexically. Unless you rewrite the method inside haml that calls that method so that it becomes within the scope of the `using` command, you cannot use refinements. But I guess haml is internally using `eval` or something like that to evaluate the code you write in a haml file. In that case, it is impossible.

Comment: Hmm.  Not entirely impossible, then, since by default haml is rendered in the binding of the object you pass to it: `Haml::Engine.new(file).render(self)`... but of course if the Sinatra code doesn't cater to it, I'm screwed for now.

Comment: ....no, wait, the `using` would have to go in the `Haml::Engine` class, wouldn't it? Damn.